# How to start a iOS App automatically and prohibit manually stop it in swift

Tags: ios, iphone

I want to create a agent app for iOS in Swift.
Is there a way to start a iOS App automatically when the iphone starts up?
And, Is there a way to prohibit manually stop a iOS App?

Comment: You have “guided access” mode (designed for educational settings where you don’t want the student straying from the course matter, IIRC) and “single app mode” (designed for corporate settings where you want to control how devices are used). Both of those are easily found in Internet searches. But, no, you can’t just have an app downloaded from the app store commandeer a users iPhone, if that’s what you’re asking...

Answer (score 0, accepted):

It is impossible to start an iOS application automatically when the iPhone starts up. For more informations take a look at the Life Cycle of an iOS app from the Apple documentation: [Managing Your App's Life Cycle](https://developer.apple.com/documentation/uikit/app_and_environment/managing_your_app_s_life_cycle)

Answer (score 0):

With the public API it's impossible. If there is a private API which would help to develop such an application, it will be impossible to publish this app to the AppStore.